# Problema com insert utilizando mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Estou trabalhando em um sistema antigo, em que faz a conexão com o banco ainda com `mysql_query`.

Utilizei muito pouco o `mysql_query` e a última vez que usei tem muito tempo, estou mais acostumado com `PDO`.

Estou tentando dar um `insert` no banco, mas a função `mysql_query` está retornando `false` e não consigo identificar o erro. Já olhei a documentação referente ao `mysql_query` e não vi nada de errado no meu código. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue o código:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $nomeVideo    = $_POST['nomeVideo'];
  $urlVideo     = $_POST['urlVideo'];
  $dataPostagem = date('d/m/Y');

  $sql = "INSERT into video (nomeVideo, urlVideo, dataPostagem)
          VALUES($nomeVideo, $urlVideo, $dataPostagem)";

  $insert = mysql_query($sql);
  var_dump($insert); exit;

  if ($insert) {
    header('Location: video.php');
  } else {
    header('Location: video.php?return=2');
  }
}
```

Eu até mudei no BD o campo `dataPostagem` de `DATE` para `VARCHAR` achando que era isso mas não resolveu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que falte as aspas nas `string` e na data:

```
$sql = "INSERT into video (nomeVideo, urlVideo, dataPostagem)
        VALUES('$nomeVideo', '$urlVideo', '$dataPostagem')";
```

Comment: -_-'  Era isso mesmo @Wendel Rodrigues. Muito obrigado, não sabia que deveria ter as aspas simples nas variáveis.

Comment: Para `string` deve sempre usar aspas no SQL.
Marca como resolvida aí ;)